# using edit link button in gridview hides select in dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In my application i have gridview with edit button. By clicking edit button in gridview the listitem of DropDownList gets replaced by the text that is in gridview these are my dropdown list values

```
--select--
Roller
Heater
```

Aspx Code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlvalue" runat="server" Width="175px" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Roller</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Heater</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

CS Code:

```
 protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ddlValue.SelectedItem.Text = (GridView1.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblValue") as Label).Text;
    }
```

Comment: please explain more if you dont explain your problem correctly. you wont get a solution here

Comment: it gets replaced because you are replacing it here
ddlValue.SelectedItem.Text = (GridView1.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblValue") as Label).Text;.

Comment: can you tell me what do you want the edit button to do instead of replacing

Comment: I think you posted this question yesterday too

Comment: ohh your code is wrong then. let me get is straight. if they select roller in gridview then you want roller to be selected in your dropdownlist right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string value = (GridView1.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblRole") as Label).Text;
            try
            {
                ddlvalue.ClearSelection();
                ddlvalue.Items.FindByText(value).Selected = true;
            }
            catch
            {
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is what you should do. you care currently changing the text of selected item instead of finding the correct item and selecting it. here is how you should do it

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

     string value=(GridView1.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblValue") as Label).Text;
     try
     {
        foreach(ListItem li in ddlValue.Items)
        {
               if(li.Text==value)
                { 
                   li.Selected=true;

                } 
                else
                {
                    li.Selected=false;
                }
        }
     }
     catch
     {
     }
}
```

Comment: This is happening because there are multiple items in your dropdownlist with the same text

Comment: changed again check

Comment: there you go. select as answer if it helped you